# Android sign-in hint not shown properly

Tags: android

I'm using google sign-in hint api to auto suggest mobile number while logging in.

[image]

It works fine in most of the devices. But in some devices and in the emulator, a dialogue is opened and dismissed automatically within a fraction of seconds each time I launch the screen.
[Adding the screen record of the same here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tmaGcI9xpvvyLVTXWUYLjUfOfEEyELQF/view).

Here is my code

```
 val build = HintRequest.Builder().setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true).build()
      val hintPickerIntent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(
          GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
              .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
              .enableAutoManage(this, this)
              .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
              .build(), build
      )

 startIntentSenderForResult(hintPickerIntent.intentSender,
          RC_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0)
```

I'm doing this in the activity `onCreate`

Any idea why is it not working in some devices?

Comment: I believe that this is the expected behavior if there are no phone numbers registered. Do the devices that have this problem, have registered numbers?

Comment: How can we check if there is a number registered or not?

Comment: "This API  displays the number(s) available on the phone or Google Account for the user to select. "  - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/effective-phone-number-verification.html . You have to check hat the phone number is linked to the Google account of the device. Some SIM cards will also show this number in the hint suggestions but I don't know which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an open ticket on the issue tracker. It looks like it's an API bug (make sure that your test devices have a number though). You can track the progress [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123654951). The latest update was about 10 days ago